# Clone A Bare Repo Locally without Link

Tags: git

I have project I'm working on. It's at a stage where I could change a few things and it could become any website, like a seed.

Note: this is on a local git server i'm running

I'd like to make a new repo out of it, and have it be it's own repo (no remotes added) so that it can be a seed for all my other projects. Since it will greatly differ from the repo it's based on, I don't want any chance of me actually pushing those changes back to original repo.

I could remove the remotes manually, but I'm sure there is a git way of going about this.

Comment: Em... why is using gits means to modify remotes not "git style"?

Comment: The title and body of your question seem to be unrelated.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, as mentioned in the answer below. I was concerned that my clone would push back to the original seed repo. But the branch answer alleviates that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a repository that has a basic site framework and build sites on that.  You're concerned you will accidentally push site specific changes back to the framework.

For each site, [make a branch](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) off the framework and work in that branch.  Then you can't accidentally push site changes to the framework.

It has other advantages.  If you update the framework, you can merge those changes into the branch.  You can push your site changes back to the main repository to serve as a backup.  You can [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) changes to a site that would be useful to the framework.  Instead of branching a new site off the framework, you can branch off a similar site for a head start.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was thinking, but I can see where it has it's benefits. I think I will try this. Thank you.

sorry for being confusing, i wasn't 100% sure what terminology to use.

Comment: @csduarte No, it's my mistake. I understood what you were asking. I failed to make clear that I ignored the idea of making them two repos. I instead focused on solving the problem of keeping the generic and specialized versions of the project separate.

Comment: No need for a detailed answer... But if I did want to keep them separate, would i just want to remove the remote origin manually when cloned?

Comment: @csduarte Yes, that is one way to do it.  You could also rename the remote, I would call it "upstream".  Then you can still get updates by `git pull upstream`.